# How to exclude some files from the minification in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I am working with Angular 6 now. Angular cli is used to build the project. It is found that some library not supporting minification. It breaks the application. I only need to exclude that files from minification

(I have an option to disable minification for all the files by turn-off the build optimizer. I don't want to use it because it will increase the file size. 
)

How to exclude the specific folder/files from minification ?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: try exclude as given https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050

Comment: As I understand it, the above link is for excluding files entirely from a build. E.g. spec files.